# How to use alias of a subquery to get the running total?

Tags: sql, ms-access, cumulative-sum

I have a `UNION` of 3 tables for calculating some balance and I need to get the running `SUM` of that balance but I can't use `PARTITION OVER`, because I must do it with a sql query that can work in Access.
My problem is that I cannot use `JOIN` on an alias subquery, it won't work.

How can I use alias in a `JOIN` to get the running total?

Or any other way to get the `SUM` that is not with `PARTITION OVER`, because it does not exist in Access.
This is my code so far:

```
SELECT korisnik_id, imePrezime, datum, Dug, Pot, (Dug - Pot) AS Balance
FROM (
    SELECT korisnik_id, k.imePrezime, r.datum, SUM(IIF(u.jedinstven = 1, r.cena, k.kvadratura * r.cena)) AS Dug, '0' AS Pot
    FROM Racun r
    INNER JOIN Usluge u ON r.usluga_id = u.ID
    INNER JOIN Korisnik k ON r.korisnik_id = k.ID
    WHERE korisnik_id = 1
        AND r.zgrada_id = 1
        AND r.mesec = 1
        AND r.godina = 2017
    GROUP BY korisnik_id, k.imePrezime, r.datum

    UNION ALL

    SELECT korisnik_id, k.imePrezime, rp.datum, SUM(IIF(u.jedinstven = 1, rp.cena, k.kvadratura * rp.cena)) AS Dug, '0' AS Pot
    FROM RacunP rp
    INNER JOIN Usluge u ON rp.usluga_id = u.ID
    INNER JOIN Korisnik k ON rp.korisnik_id = k.ID
    WHERE korisnik_id = 1
        AND rp.zgrada_id = 1
        AND rp.mesec = 1
        AND rp.godina = 2017
    GROUP BY korisnik_id, k.imePrezime, rp.datum

    UNION ALL

    SELECT uu.korisnik_id, k.imePrezime, uu.datum, '0' AS Dug, SUM(uu.iznos) AS Pot
    FROM UnosUplata uu
    INNER JOIN Korisnik k ON uu.korisnik_id = k.ID
    WHERE korisnik_id = 1
    GROUP BY uu.korisnik_id, k.imePrezime, uu.datum
    ) AS a
ORDER BY korisnik_id
```

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` or `MS Access` ?

Comment: Have you done a search on running total, running balance, running sum? Common topic. Easiest method is to use RunningSum property of textbox on report.

Comment: I am using MS Access. I have solved my problem using running sum in crystal report, I didn't find how to do it in the sql query. I have searched, but every query does a join with the table itself. Here my table has an alias,and I can't join on the alias itself

Comment: Make a view on that query and then use alias on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a query (let's name it `Query1`) for the `UNION` of the 3 tables and then create another query that returns each row in the first query and calculates the sum of the rows that are before it (optionally checking that they are in the same group).

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Query1 AS b 
    WHERE b.GroupNumber=a.GroupNumber
    AND b.Position<=a.Position
) AS RunningSum
FROM Query1 AS a
```

However, it's more efficient to do that in the report.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if saving and using query will work, because I am using C# and OleDb.

Comment: For the moment, I am calculating the total in the report, but it is good to know this answer also :)